# How to place Google adsense in Meteor.js app?

Tags: meteor, iron-router, adsense

No Ads are showing up? I've got no clue why.

myAds.html

```
<template name="myAds">
   <div class="ads"></div>
</template>
```

myAds.js

```
Template.myAds.onRendered = function() {  
  $.getScript("//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js", function() {
    var ads, adsbygoogle;
    ads = '<ins class="adsbygoogle" style="display:block" data-ad-client="ca-pub-ca-pub-7023*********1" data-ad-slot="58*****42" data-ad-format="auto"></ins>';
    $('.ads').html(ads);
    return (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
  });
};
```

router.js

```
Router.map( function () {
  this.route('MyRoute', {
    waitOn: function() {
      return IRLibLoader.load("//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js");
    }
  });
});
```

ShowAdHere.html

```
{{ > myAds }}
```

Comment: Any error on the console maybe?

Answer (score 1):

```
   <head>
    "<script async src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>"
   </head>
```

Have you added this ?

Comment: added it to myAds.html - nothing. tried ShowAdHere.html - nothing.